# Pass Dates Range in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

I'm connecting to an API and in the Body I need to specify the date range for the data. Is it possible to make this dynamic so it will show today's date instead of the static 
`"2022-06-10T16:30:34.516Z"`, as shown below?

```
$body= @"
{"sort":[{"field":"createdOn","direction":"desc"}],"filter":{"operator":"gt","field":"createdOn","value":"2022-06-10T16:30:34.516Z"},"fields":[],"page":{"length":100,"offset":0}}
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do it.

Basically you want to convert the json to a PSObject, edit the value you are interested in and convert it back.

The conversion process take care of escaping characters as needed.

**Example**

```
$body = @"
{"sort":[{"field":"createdOn","direction":"desc"}],"filter":{"operator":"gt","field":"createdOn","value":"2022-06-10T16:30:34.516Z"},"fields":[],"page":{"length":100,"offset":0}}
"@


# Convert the json to a PSObject to edit it
$jsonObj = $body | ConvertFrom-Json

# Set the date
$jsonObj.filter.value = Get-Date

# Your new Json.
$body = $jsonObj | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're constructing the JSON string yourself, so you can use PowerShell's *string interpolation*:

```
$body= @"
... "value":"$([datetime]::UtcNow.ToString('o'))"} ...
"@
```

Note the use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), which is required to embed the value of expressions and even whole statements inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), including in the [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) variant being used here.

Note that `[datetime]::UtcNow.ToString('o')` produces a string such as 
`'2022-06-10T16:30:34.5161234Z'`, i.e. a format with *4 additional decimal places* compared to the example in your question.